# codeigniter search query with most recent time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables in db messages and messages_recipient

messages table have following columns

**message_id   user_id   message     created_at**

messages_recipient table have following columns

**message_recipient_id   user_id   message_id**

sender id is stored in messages and receiver id is stored in messages_recipient

I have the following query to get the messages that are send to user that is log in

```
$this->db->select('messages.user_id');
  $this->db->from('messages');
  $this->db->join('messages_recipients','messages.message_id= messages_recipients.message_id');
  $this->db->where( 'messages_recipients.user_id',$sende_id );
  $query = $this->db->get();
```

it gives all the messages send to the user but i want to get the messages that are most recent send to user from same user

Comment: `most recent`    in which way you are asking i.e. where time different is less than minute or something else???

Comment: means in db which is last i.e 2 message form the same user it should view  only the message which have greater time than the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use query like

```
$this->db->select('messages.user_id');
  $this->db->from('messages');
  $this->db->join('messages_recipients','messages.message_id= messages_recipients.message_id');
  $this->db->where( 'messages_recipients.user_id',$sende_id );
  $this->db->order_by("created_at", "desc");
  $this->db->limit(1);
```

Simply here i am arranging your rows in descending order of Date and selecting the first row i.e. latest one.

Hope this might solve your problem.

Comment: Dear Abbas , you've forgot the the query to fetch result from the DB. Please update the answer and use : $this->db->get(); function

Answer (score 1):

```
  $this->db->select('messages.user_id');
  $this->db->from('messages');
  $this->db->join('messages_recipients','messages.message_id = messages_recipients.message_id');
  $this->db->where( 'messages_recipients.user_id',$sende_id );
  $this->db->order_by("created_at", "desc");
  $this->db->limit(2);
  $query = $this->db->get();
```

May be this could help..
Use order by function and limit in code-igniter and you will achieve what you want.